# One or more rows submitted for batch updating is missing the specified index. (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am Using Update_batch to my model and it gives me following error

One or more rows submitted for batch updating is missing the specified index.

**Following is my Model:**

```
function approvedHrs($id,$taskid,$update_data)
{
   // $where=array('id','taskid');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->where('taskid', $taskid);
     $this->db->update_batch('MILESTONE', $update_data,'approvedhrs');
}
```

**Following is my Controller:-**

```
function approvedHrs($editid,$taskid)
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){       
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $id = $session_data['id'];
            $username = $session_data['username'];
            $is_master_admin = $session_data['master'];
            $imagethumb = $session_data['imagethumb'];
            $pendingbug = $this->bugmodel->getBug($id, $is_master_admin);
            $pendingtask = $this->taskmodel->getTask($id, $is_master_admin);

            $post  =   $this->input->post();              
            $data['approvedhrs']   =   $post['approvedhrs'];
            $data['approvedmins']  =   $post['approvedmins'];
            $darpan=count($data['approvedhrs']);

            for($i=0;$i<$darpan;$i++)
            {
                $update_data['approvedhrs']     =   $data['approvedhrs'][$i];
                $update_data['approvedmins']    =   $data['approvedmins'][$i];
                //$taskid                         =   $data['taskid'][$i];
                $result = $this->milestonemodel->approvedHrs($editid,$taskid,$update_data);
                unset($update_data);
                unset($taskid);
            }

                redirect('task', 'refresh');
      }
      else 
      {
              redirect('login', 'refresh');
      }
    }
```

How can i Solve This issue??

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the function _update_batch which is located in file /system/database/DB_query_builder.php:

```
$index_escaped = $this->protect_identifiers($index);

    $ids = array();
    foreach ($values as $key => $val)
    {
        $ids[] = $val[$index];

        foreach (array_keys($val) as $field)
        {
            if ($field !== $index)
            {
                $final[$field][] = 'WHEN '.$index_escaped.' = '.$val[$index].' THEN '.$val[$field];
            }
        }
    }
```

Replace variable $index with $index_escaped:

```
$index_escaped = $this->protect_identifiers($index);

    $ids = array();
    foreach ($values as $key => $val)
    {
        $ids[] = $val[$index_escaped];

        foreach (array_keys($val) as $field)
        {
            if ($field !== $index_escaped)
            {
                $final[$field][] = 'WHEN '.$index_escaped.' = '.$val[$index_escaped].' THEN '.$val[$field];
            }
        }
    }
```